# Tables in R fill with NAs instead of values

Tags: r, na

My dataset has many rows and 6 columns, one of which is the `country ("cntry").` I would like to calculate the means of every variable by country group.

```
cntry N      mean(euftf) mean(trstep) mean(x)
BE    20     5.67        4.87         9.22
LK    32     4.33        6.77         9.87
```

I have tried this with the following:

```
group_by(df, cntry) %>% summarize(m = mean(euftf))
```

...and many others. The problem is that my tables looks good, but all the values are always NA's, no matter what I do (NA's are omitted in `df` already).

Does anyone have a clue why...?

Comment: Are you sure ```df``` has no NA values? You can try ```group_by(df, cntry) %>% summarize(m = mean(euftf, na.rm = TRUE))``` and that should definitely remove any NAs before calculating the mean.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it. Not sure why, but the na.omit command did not get rid of all NAs.